# SVG kit for ios,file not found error

Tags: ios, svg

/usr/include/libxml2 I am trying to integrate SVG kit in my ios project.I tried these steps

```
Open "SVGKit-iOS.xcodeproj", and Build it (cmd-B)
in left navbar, scroll to bottom, and open the "Products" section
right click the library ("libSVGKitBLAHBLAH.a") and select "show in finder"
GO UP ONE FOLDER
select the "Debug-universal" (or Release-universal if you were building in Release mode) folder
Drag/drop the .a file and the "usr" folder into your project (select the "Copy files" checkbox)
In Build Settings, select "Other Linker Flags" and add "-ObjC"
Edit your build settings and set "C/C++ Compiler Version" = "LLVM Compiler"
Edit your build settings and add "Other Linker Flags" = "-ObjC"
Add ALL the frameworks and 3rd party libraries listed below (go to "Build Phases", and "Link Binary with Libraries"):
    CoreText
    CoreImage
    libxml2.dylib
    QuartzCore
    CoreGraphics
    UIKit
```

As per the documentation,however when i try to import the header file,it says file not found.The header search path /usr/include/libxml2 is also there.Please advise what i am missing

Answer (score 0):

You should copy .a file and contents of usr/local/include folder and paste them to another place. Then in your project from Xcode right click->"Add files to ..." and add those copied files. Make sure you check "Copy items if needed"